# Squid with mysql

Tags: mysql, squid

I want to setup squid like all users and groups / acl are fetch from mysql database in centos 6.5. I tried a lot but I did not find any package or method to setup it.

Username, passwords and acl are dynamically change and based on changes squid has to provide access.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible using external_acl or rewrite_program.
For programtion use C, Perl, PHP, ShellScript.
You need only return `ERR` for negation or `OK` for allow the access.
On external_acl you can pass to program any parrametres, url, port destination, port source, ip source, domain destionation, user.

basic example, allow access the "google"

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
include "mysql.php";
include "funcoes.php";

$temp = array();
stream_set_timeout(STDIN, 86400);
if (!defined(STDIN)) {
define("STDIN", fopen("php://stdin", "r"));
}


while (!feof(STDIN)) {
$input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$found = 0;
$login = 0;
$temp = split(' ', $input);
$output = $temp[0] . "\n";
$url_output = $output;
$url_output_debug = $temp[0];

$pos = strpos($url_output, 'google');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $output = "OK \n";
    $found = 1;
} else {
    $output = "ERR \n";
}

fwrite(STDOUT, $output);
}
?>
```